# Encoding utf8 with php

Tags: php, encoding

im trying to encode a database in utf8, but nothing work. I think i must change the class functions.php('funciones in spanish'), this is my code:

```
`<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "myvinoalb", "EupN7FNM");
    $dbname = "xxx";
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$link) OR DIE ("Error: Imposible Conectar");
?>`
```

Comment: utf8_encode(string)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/2780941) you go. And DO NOT USE mysql_* functions any more! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/2780941) is why.